# JQuery unselect button when another button is clicked

Tags: jquery, tabs, highlight

I am new to stack overflow and I have already searched for other answers on this site. I found something similar but the problem there was using other, premade tabs and my limited knowledge of JQuery couldn't help me make out a solution to my problem according to the other one.

So, basically I started learning JQuery and my assignment asks from me to create a simple tab representation. My problem is that when I select a button and highlight it, the highlight should go away when another button is selected, but it doesn't.

Here's the JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".tab").hide();
        $("[id=1]").show();
        $("#switcher .button").click(function(){                
            var a = $(this).attr("title");
            $(".tab").hide();
            $("[id="+a+"]").show();
            $("[val="+a+"]").addClass("button1");
        }); 
        $("[val="+a+"]").addClass('button');
    });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div id="switcher" class="switcher">
    <div class="label"><i>Custom tab</i></div>
    <div val="1" title="1" class="button">Open Start</div>
    <div val="2" title="2" class="button">Connect</div>
    <div val="3" title="3" class="button">Pin apps</div>
  </div>
  <div id="1" class="tab">Tab1 text</div>
  <div id="2" class="tab">Tab2 text</div>
  <div id="3" class="tab">Tab3 text</div>
</div>
```

In my CSS, I have button as the normal button whereas button1 is the class that has changed background text and text decoration.
If anyone can help, I'd be grateful. Thanks :)

Comment: why dont you just .removeClass('button1') for all of them when an item is clicked and then .addClass("button1").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `button1` class from all `button`:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".tab").hide();
    $("[id=1]").show();
    $("#switcher .button").click(function(){                
        var a = $(this).attr("title");
        $(".tab").hide();
        $("[id="+a+"]").show();
        $('.button').removeClass('button1'); //Add this line.
        $("[val="+a+"]").addClass("button1");
    }); 
    $("[val="+a+"]").addClass('button');
});
```

Comment: i second this answer - beat me to posting by a few seconds :)

Comment: Thanks both of you, the solution you posted works. I can't believe it was this simple :)